# Use variables in PostgreSQL/PostGIS code

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I'd like to create an SQL file, where the user can just change variables on the beginning , and use it in different configuration system. Typically for load layer from different PostGIS server with postgres_fdw.

I tried it with PL/pgSQL where I can declare variables before beginning processing, but I don't no how to use them after...

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
    url character := '193.00.00.00';  
    pt character := '5432';  
    db character := 'bd_name';  
    usr character := 'user_name';
    pwd character := 'password';
BEGIN  
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

    CREATE SERVER foreign_srv
        FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
        OPTIONS (host url, port pt, dbname db);

    CREATE USER MAPPING FOR USER
        SERVER foreign_srv
        OPTIONS (user usr, password pwd);

END $$;
```

It obviously doesn't work like that.

Comment: This shows how to use the variables http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-variables/

Comment: Do you want the users to be running pl/pgsql or do you want them to use standard sql queries? common table expressions could be used to accomplish this using standard SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution with '||quote_literal(variable)||'. For my example :

```
DO $$
DECLARE  
    url character := '193.00.00.00';  
    pt character := '5432';  
    db character := 'bd_name';  
    usr character := 'user_name';
    pwd character := 'password';
BEGIN  
    CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgres_fdw;

    EXECUTE 'CREATE SERVER foreign_bd_ign 
    FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw 
    OPTIONS (host '||quote_literal(url)||', port '||quote_literal(pt)||', dbname '||quote_literal(db)||')';

    EXECUTE 'CREATE USER MAPPING FOR 
    USER SERVER foreign_bd_ign 
    OPTIONS (user '||quote_literal(usr)||', password '||quote_literal(pwd)||')';

END;
$$;
```

Answer (score 3):

What if you tried the EXECUTE command:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE SERVER foreign_srv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host $1, port $2, dbname $3)' USING url, pt, db;
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/plpgsql-statements.html

There are a bunch of different ways this execute command can be used. Variations of format, %s, %L, etc.. You'll have to look up how to implement in your case. Here's another example on how to use for reference:

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE  
    db character varying := 'D_C';
    a character varying := 'test_char1';  
    b character varying := 'test_int';  
    c character varying := 'test_char2';
BEGIN  
    EXECUTE format('CREATE table %s.cls_del (%s character varying, %s integer, %s double precision)', db, a, b, c);
END $$;
```

Comment: It give me an error : postgres error syntax error at or near "$1" Context : fonction "PL/pgsql inline_code_block, line 11 at EXECUTE

Answer (score 1):

You can use EXECUTE command with a concatenated string (with USING like @D_C said, or like the following), but don't forget these parameters need to be encapsulated with '', so you need to escape with \' if you are already in a string:

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE SERVER foreign_srv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host \''||url||'\', port \''||pt||'\', dbname \''||db||'\')';
```

It should work with using? :

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE SERVER foreign_srv
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
OPTIONS (host \'$1\', port \'$2\', dbname \'$3\')' USING url, pt, db;
```

Comment: Thanks for insert method with ||, it's work. But \' don't work. I've fund the solution by use '||quote_literal(variable)||'

Comment: Strange, I though it should work... Anyway your solution is way better! There is also the $$ string apparently, as another solution (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316953/insert-text-with-single-quotes-in-postgresql)